# Copy and Filter XML based on a condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a XSLT which needs to copy the entire XML maintaining the same structure and filtering out some nodes based on a condition.

in the below example i need to keep only the nodes where IsBusinness = Y

```
<CompanyTypes>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
       <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
       <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
        <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
     </CompanyType>
  </Parent1>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test1</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
       <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
       <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
       <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
     </CompanyType>
  </Parent1>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test3</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test9</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
      <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
      <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
      <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
      <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
    </CompanyType>
   </Parent1>
 </CompanyTypes>
```

desired output

```
<CompanyTypes>
<Parent1>
   <ChildNode1>Test1</ChildNode1>
   <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
   <CompanyType>
      <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
      <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
      <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
      <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
   </CompanyType>
 </Parent1>
 <Parent1>
   <ChildNode1>Test3</ChildNode1>
   <ChildNode2>Test9</ChildNode2>
   <CompanyType>
      <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
      <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
      <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
      <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
   </CompanyType>
 </Parent1>
</CompanyTypes>
```

Comment: This is a very simple exercise. What did you try so we can help you learn XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 <!-- Identical Template to copy all structure -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This template delete all CompanyType which node IsBusinness != Y -->    
    <xsl:template match="Parent1[CompanyType/IsBusiness != 'Y']"/>
```

See transform at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfV/1

**Output**

```
<CompanyTypes>
       <Parent1>
          <ChildNode1>Test1</ChildNode1>
          <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
          <CompanyType>
             <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
             <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
             <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
             <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
          </CompanyType>
       </Parent1>
       <Parent1>
          <ChildNode1>Test3</ChildNode1>
          <ChildNode2>Test9</ChildNode2>
          <CompanyType>
             <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
             <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
             <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
             <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
          </CompanyType>
       </Parent1>
    </CompanyTypes>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact scenario that i looking for, can you please help me with that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I would also like to remove the nodes that dont have <IsBusiness> tag at all, can anyone please help me with that.