# Copy and Filter XML based on a condition and remove parent node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a XSLT which needs to copy the entire XML maintaining the same structure and filtering out some nodes based on a condition.

in the below example i need to keep only the nodes where IsBusinness = Y

```
<CompanyTypes>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
       <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
       <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
       <IsBusiness>N</IsBusiness>
    </CompanyType>
  </Parent1>
  <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test1</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
       <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
       <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
       <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
    </CompanyType>
   </Parent1>
   <Parent1>
     <ChildNode1>Test3</ChildNode1>
     <ChildNode2>Test9</ChildNode2>
     <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
       <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
       <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
       <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
      </CompanyType>
    </Parent1>
   </CompanyTypes>
```

desired output

```
  <CompanyTypes>
    <Parent1>
    <ChildNode1>Test1</ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2>Test</ChildNode2>
    <CompanyType>
       <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
        <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
        <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
        <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
        </CompanyType>
     </Parent1>
     <Parent1>
         <ChildNode1>Test3</ChildNode1>
         <ChildNode2>Test9</ChildNode2>
         <CompanyType>
            <CompanyTypeID>1</CompanyTypeID>
            <CompanyTypeName>Individual</CompanyTypeName>
            <CompanyTypeDesc>Individual</CompanyTypeDesc>
            <IsBusiness>Y</IsBusiness>
          </CompanyType>
          </Parent1> 
       </CompanyTypes>
```

Comment: Please include in your question the XSLT stylesheet you are working on, and point out in what way it is not producing the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy and Filter XML based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588670/copy-and-filter-xml-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 0):

To omit `Parent1` elements other than containing `IsBusiness` == 'Y',
you need to include an **empty template** for such elements:

```
<xsl:template match="Parent1[not(CompanyType/IsBusiness = 'Y')]"/>
```

Of course, the script should contain also the *identity template*.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Parent1[not(CompanyType/IsBusiness = 'Y')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code:-

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Parent1/CompanyType[IsBusiness != 'Y']"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />        
    <xsl:template match="CompanyTypes">
        <CompanyTypes>
            <xsl:for-each select="Parent1[CompanyType/IsBusiness='Y']">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </CompanyTypes>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You certainly do not need the first template.